# R leaflet search doesn't zoom to correct place after clicking search result

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I've set up a map of local voting precincts and want to be able to search precinct number. The goal is that the user can type a precinct number into the search box, click the correct precinct, and the map would zoom to that precinct.

Instead, when a user searches a precinct number, Leaflet returns the full contents of the precinct's mouseover label information, and when the user clicks that result, the map shows an error saying "Location not found."

Code below, Github repo with [original shapefile and CSV data file here](https://github.com/chrismp/r-leaflet-search-problem).

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(htmltools)
library(tigris)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(dplyr)

m16 <- geo_join(
  spatial_data = readOGR(
    dsn = "Precinct_2016/PRECINCT_REDISTRICTING_region.shp",
    layer = "PRECINCT_REDISTRICTING_region"
  ),
  data_frame = read.csv("2016 results by precinct.csv"),
  by_sp = "PRECINCT",
  by_df = "Precinct",
  how = "inner"
)

label16 <- sprintf(
  fmt = "<strong>Precinct %s</strong><br>
        Hillary Clinton: %g (%g%%) <br>
        Donald Trump: %g (%g%%) <br>",
  m16$Precinct, m16$Hillary.Rodham.Clinton, m16$Percent.Clinton, m16$Donald.J..Trump, m16$Percent.Trump
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons(
    data = m16,
    group = "2016",
    label = label16
  ) %>%
  addSearchFeatures(
    targetGroups = "2016",
    options = searchFeaturesOptions(
      textPlaceholder = "Search precinct"
    )
  )
```